# How to add a "or" to my query (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I want to filter users by `email`, `name` and/or `phone`.

I have this in my `usuarios_controller.rb`:

```
if params[:usuario]
  @usuarios = Usuario.where({:Email => params[:usuario] }).order('created_at DESC')
end
```

How do I add a "OR" to this?

I want an OR condition among all these parameters.

Comment: Haven't used MongoDB for awhile but `order('created_at desc')` looks like ActiveRecord/SQL to me but your question is tagged `mongodb`. Is this ActiveRecord or Mongoid/MongoMapper?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OR` in `where` method like following:

```
Usuario.where("email = ? OR name = ? or phone = ?", email_value, name_value, phone_value)
```

It will build and execute the following SQL query:

```
SELECT "usuarios".* FROM "usuarios" WHERE (email = 'email_value' OR name = 'name_value' or phone = 'phone_value')
```